# Is there going to an issue running different features of WP site in different subdomains?

Tags: plugins, multisite, installation, troubleshooting

I have a main site running in `mydomain.com`. I want to install an e-commerce plugin and want to run it in a subdomain `shop.mydomain.com`. In the future I may want to install an LMS plugin and run it in `lms.mydomain.com`. LMS will need to directly interact with the e-commerce because people may subscribe to courses and pay via the e-commerce plugin. Does this make it more complicated? Should I just install everything in the main domain and make life easier?

Answer (score 0):

Different sites can have different plugins enabled, different sets of users, etc. That's built in to Multisite.

The "LMS talking to ecommerce" part will probably require you (or someone you hire) to write some code -- a head start might be to look at [`switch_to_blog()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/switch_to_blog) and [`restore_current_blog()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/restore_current_blog), and indeed [the list of Multisite functions](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/#Multisite_functions). (Or you can enable the ecommerce plugin on the LMS site as well.)

Comment: I am not too familiar with the multisite feature. For my requirements, is it best to use multisite or single site installation? From what I have read, multisite is a good option if I want to allow people to create their own sites within WP or something like that?

Comment: You could certainly use Multisite to have your three domains -- `mydomain.com`, `shop.mydomain.com`, and `lms.mydomain.com` -- running on one WordPress installation. It would also allow you to have the LMS site retrieve data from the ecommerce site. You can red up on Multisite here: [Before You Create a Network](https://codex.wordpress.org/Before_You_Create_A_Network).